# Different Record Count in two exactly reports but created on different dates

Tags: reporting, filters

I have two reports created from the same Standard Report Type, using the same filters, one created in 2016 by a user who is no longer active, and another created today with my user, and I get two different totals.

Do you know why this is?

[image]

Thank you so much for your help

Mónica Martínez

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward explanation. What happens if you take away all filter on both reports? You could identify this way if the difference is due to report types or filters.

Comment: Without filters I still have differences in the results. Report 2016, 11898, Report 2023, 11903

Comment: Interesting.. And you're sure that there are no 2 Report Types with the same name (not sure if that's even possible..)

Comment: Could maybe be a case of sharing/FLS settings that are interfering with the number of records that are displayed for **you** VS the **past user**. Troubleshooting: -FLS settings for the fields. -Sharing Rules for the records in question.

Comment: I am sure that the report type in both cases is the same.

Comment: In that case I can't explain and would advise to log a case with Salesforce Support (and let us know the outcome here).